# Last day of previous month in yyyymmdd format

Tags: sql-server

I have tried this, but I need it in this format `yyyymmdd` and not `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
select convert(
   varchar(10),
   dateadd(s,-1,dateadd(mm,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)),
   120
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles):

```
SELECT CONVERT (
   varchar(8),
   dateadd(s, -1, dateadd(mm, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0)),
   112
)
```

As an additional note, `EOMONTH()` (with `-1` as second parameter, as @Larnu mentioned in his answer) is also an option:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1), 112)
```

Answer (score 1):

`EOMONTH` has a second parameter, so you can simply do:

```
EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

As for the format, that's for your presentation layer, not the RDBMS; leave it as a strongly typed `date` value.